# Tuleap tracker configuration

Tags: tuleap

I try to make a some dynamique field with three different traker (for example Track1, Track2, Track3).

**My config :**

- Track2 have artifact linked with artifact Track1
- Track3 is a child of Track2

**Problem 1 :**

So when I create a new artifact on Track3 I can select an artifact of Track2 with the artifact link.

What I want is that : when I create a new Track3 artifact I can select the parent (artifact Track2), I want to display the link (artifact Track1) of the Track2 artifact on the submit page.

I try with Shared field but I can't use a cross reference field id.

**Problem 2 :**

I want to use a Selectbox and hide/display String field if a particulary value is selected.
Or change text on a Text field if Selectbox value is choosen. For that I try to use the dependencies manager but I have not access to Textfield in target field.

I hope I'm clear and thank for your help.

Comment: I don't undestand Problem1, could you rephrase it with a concrete use case (with a bug or a user story, ...) instead of abstract Track1,2,3..

Comment: Okais, I have a traker of Contact, Station and Ticket. Each artifact of Station is linked with one or more artifact of Contact. Ticket is a child of Station. When you create an artifact of Ticket you have to select an artifact of Station (to follow which station is in trouble). What I need is that : when I select the station during the creation I want to display the list of Contact linked on the Station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both issues are not solvable with Tuleap web UI as of today, but you can post a feature request, propose a contribution and/or finance the development of such a feature: https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?tracker=140

An alternative for **Problem 1** would be to leverage the REST api to build your own interface to present the informations you need.